# Implementation of class in Python

Tags: python, oop

The problem is to implement scalar and inner product in the vector class in Python. Here is the code:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Point(%s, %s)' % (self.x, self.y)
    def __mul__(self,other):
        x, y = self.x*other.x, self.y*other.y
        return self.__class__(x,y)
    def __rmul__(self,other):
        x,y = other*self.x,other*self.y
        return self.__class__(x,y)
    def __add__(self,other):
        x,y = self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y
        return self.__class__(x, y)
    def __sub__(self,other):
        x,y = self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y
        return self.__class__(x, y)
```

With inner product it works great, but with scalar multiplication(like if I call Point(3,2)*2) it gives the following error:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'x'.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You could check the type of `other` in `__mul__`.

Comment: What kind of vector multiplication are you doing? A dot product between vectors is a number, not a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully at your `__mul__` method:

```py
    def __mul__(self,other):
        x, y = self.x*other.x, self.y*other.y
        return self.__class__(x,y)
```

When you're trying to multiply a `Point` and an `int`, you're passing the `int` as the second argument (to the `other` parameter) to `Point.__mul__`. Then your method will try to access `other.x` and `other.y`, and an `int` doesn't have these attributes:

You can manually check for the type of `other` and decide whether you should be doing scalar or vector product:

```py
    def __mul__(self,other):
        if isinstance(other, Point):
            x, y = self.x*other.x, self.y*other.y
            return self.__class__(x,y)
        elif isinstance(other, (int, float, complex)):
            x, y = other * self.x, other * self.y
            return self.__class__(x, y)
        else:
            raise TypeError

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return self * other
```

Also, the way you're doing multiplication is strange. A dot product of two vectors should be a number, not a vector.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product

Comment: Thank you, the answer is very helpful. Yes, I messed up with definition a little bit, it should be like x1*x2 +y1*y2. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a check for the type of `other`, it can be a Point instance or other

Here the code for `__mul__`

```
def __mul__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Point):
        return Point(self.x * other.x, self.y * other.y)  # Point * Point
    return Point(self.x * other, self.y * other)          # Point * othertype

def __rmul__(self, other):
    return Point(self.x * other, self.y * other)          # othertype * Point
```